# How to invoke Android native code from Rikulu?

Tags: android, android-intent, cordova, dart, rikulo

[Rikulo](http://rikulo.org/) sounds like a great framework for developing to several platforms using 1 code base and 1 language. **BUT**, I'm missing some key integration - Firing Intents.

I found some integration with native capabilities (using [Rikulo Gap](http://docs.rikulo.org/ui/latest/Rikulo_Gap/Fundamentals.html)), but missing other native capabilities, like firing intents in Android. Perhaps it's on purpose, because only Android has Intents and Rikulo is targeted towards additional platforms as well.

So, is there an option to run platform specific code in Rikulo? Specifically firing Android intents? Thanks.

Comment: Whoever down-voted the question, please explain why, so me or others could improve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The way Rikulo access to android native capabilities is via Rikulo Gap. What Rikulo Gap has done is to bridge dart APIs to Cordova(PhoneGap)'s JavaScript APIs and vice versa. Unless Cordova supports the fire-intents API of android that we can "bridge" to, there might not be easy way to accomplish this request.

Comment: I see that embedding native android code can be accomplished in Phonegap using CordovaPlugin. Can CordovaPlugin be used in Rikulo?

Comment: As long as you can access to native android code via JavaScript, it is possible to write Dart "bridge" code to bridge from "Dart" APIs to "JavaScript" APIs.